# iOS UIInputViewController: present Custom UIViewController + NIB

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, nib

I've a keyboard extension and want to present a custom UIViewController with a NIB file inside an UIInputViewController. I already made some custom keyboards with ObjectiveC in the past. There I could set a UiNavigationController to the UIInputViewController. But it seems that this is not possible anymore.

- Does anyone knows how to do that?
- Or does anyone knows a good tutorial?

Here is some sample code that doesn't work.

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let controller: MyViewController = MyViewController()
    self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem:

I just put the code into `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let controller: MyViewController = MyViewController()
    self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```